# Is "indices" or "indexes" the plural of "index"?

Tags: plural-forms, word-form, latin

I've heard both plural forms of **index**, **indices** and **indexes**. I usually use **indices** when referring to the computer science term for **database index**, but I'm not sure if it is correct in that context.

Are both **indices** and **indexes** correct? If  only one of them is correct, which one?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Both are correct](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=321709), though there are [some specific usages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/84/24) as pointed in another answer; Google Ngrams [suggests](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indices,indexes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) that *indices* is slightly more used than *indexes*.

For American English we have (in both charts, *indices* is blue and *indexes* is red):

[image]

For British English we have:

[image]

Comment: This may be different for British and American English. Might be worth trying the Ngram search against those corpuses separately.

Comment: @MετάEd done: added those results to my answer.

Comment: Check my answer. Different forms are also supposed to be used in different contexts.

Comment: This doesn't account for *indexes* being used as both a noun and a verb

Answer (score 9):

OED [states](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/94372#eid674233):

> **Forms**:  Pl. **indexes** (also 16 **index's**) and **indices** /ˈɪndɪsiːz/ .
>
> **Etymology**:  < Latin *inde*, *indic-em*, plural *indicēs*, the forefinger, an informer, sign, inscription. [...]
>
> In current use the plural is *indices* in senses 8, 9, and usually in other senses except 5, in which *indexes* is usual.

And the respective senses are: (5): index in the end of the book *etc.*; (8): mathematical index, and (9):

> **9.** In various sciences, a number or formula expressing some property, form, ratio, etc. of the thing in question.

Comment: Also, an index can be a financial instrument. NASDAQ says in [IS IT INDEXES OR INDICES?](http://www.nasdaqomx.com/transactions/indexes/indexesorindices/) _You will likely see the words "indexes" and "indices" used interchangeably when exchanges or financial news outlets refer to more than one index, but "indices" has been more widely adopted in texts referring to stock related index._

Comment: You forgot to mention [The Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_Librorum_Prohibitorum), managed since 1559 by the "Sacred Congregation of the Index" (sounds like a Monty Python creation, but it was not funny), which listed the publications that were not to be read because contradicting Rome, including. heliocentrism theories, or books from Descartes, Victor Hugo or Simone de Beauvoir. This list of evil books lasted until... 1966, so the Internet (miraculously) escaped the Sacred Congregation management!

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, either one is correct.

Unfortunately, the problem goes far beyond this particular noun to pretty much all nouns of direct Latin descent.  As people study Latin less and less, the use of Latin plural forms is slowly eroding.  In general, the more a word has found its way into common usage, the more likely that the English plural has replaced the Latin.

For example, "status" is both the singular and plural form in Latin, but "statuses" is common even though it sounds awkward, presumably because we want to have different words for singular and plural.  We all speak of "an agenda," when actually "some agenda" is correct in the Latin sense; one of a group of agenda is an "agendum,"  Similarly, one item of data is a datum, but we rarely say "the data are on the way," and the word "datum" is very rare; people usually prefer to say something like "a unit of data."  And I don't see "fora" in place of "forums" except in forums that I would never join.  :)

On the other hand, we generally say "appendices," I suspect primarily because "appendixes" sounds funny.  I see both "curricula" and "curriculums."  Further, though, I never see "genuses," always "genera," and likewise for "quantums" vs. "quanta."

Then, "news medium" and "news media" are always used, while "mediums" are people who hold séances and call up ghosts. So, what we do is rather arbitrary.

Comment: *Multimedia* looks like a jewel. Something curious to me is why roman ([Roma](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulus_and_Remus)) metamorphosed into [romance](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_(love)) in *romance languages* or *[romance standard time](https://www.karhukoti.com/WorldTimeDate/?tz=Romance%20Standard%20Time)* (exception: Roman fonts vs. Italic fonts). Likely a common evolution for many borrowed words (e.g. Italian confetto (s.) / confetti (pl.) is used in French as confetti (s.) and confettis (pl.), two approximations at once!).

Answer (score 6):

Both *indexes* and *indices* are [correct](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/index_1). A question like this can be settled by checking a good dictionary. I checked my answer by going to *[OneLook.com](http://OneLook.com/)*, a great starting point for many online English dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct, though *indexes* is more commonly associated with the index reference of a book, while *indices* tends to be used with numerical symbols and ratios.